# Trying to multithread a breadth-first search

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception, parallel-processing, null

I've been trying to parallelize a breadth-first search for homework and I have semi-working code so far. For some cases it works (though I can't say if necessarily faster) and for some it throws an exception because `Sucessors()` is not defined for a `null`. However, as far as I can see, there should never be a `null` in my queue `q`. It always starts with 1 item in `q`, then I take all the items from `q` and place them into queue `r` so I have a complete layer of the tree and can add the next layer back into `q`. Then I want to parallelly find all successors for each item in `r` and for any new states (which is checked by `Sucessor()`) to be added back into `q` if there are any and no solution has been found yet. Checking whether a state has already been reached isn't locked so old states might be revisited, but this should only add some double work. Does anyone know how a `null` can get into `r`?

```
// Do BFS
            while (true)
            {
                while (q.Count > 0)
                {
                    Tuple<byte[], Solution> currentState = q.Dequeue();
                    r.Enqueue(currentState);
                }
                // Generate sucessors, and push them on to the queue if they haven't been seen before
                Parallel.ForEach(r, state =>
                {
                        foreach (Tuple<byte[], Solution> next in Sucessors(state))
                        {

                            if (next.Item1[targetVehicle] == goal)
                            {

                                    foundSolution = next.Item2;
                                    solfound = true;

                            }
                            if (next != null)
                            q.Enqueue(next);
                        }

                }
                    );
                if (solfound == true || q == null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(foundSolution);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    break;
                }
            }
```

EDIT: I've made `q` into a ConcurrentQueue since the enqueue caused some problems sometimes. This actually solved the null-reference, but now the program is significantly slower in parallel then in serial. And it somehow fails to recognize unbeatable boards even after locking the checking of old states.

Comment: Can you upload a complete, executable solution somewhere? Parallel perf problems are hard to diagnose without quite complete code.

Comment: I've uploaded it in a zip here: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=32267368689194633953  

Edit: some example inputs:
1
12 2
10 0
.xx......q..
.........q..



1
12 6
10 2
..cddd...q..
a.ce.....q..
axxe.....q..
bbryyi......
.gruui......
.gtt.i...zz.

Comment: Not sure how to enter them. Can you hard-code them so I can just run the program?